# Split .txt file into words and store each word in array

Tags: c, arrays, string

Let's say my file has about 1000 words with commas, dots and semicolons.
I have to split the text into words (probably using "strtok", but I don't know how to do this correctly) and then write these words into array. How to do such a thing? Can somebody write a piece of working code and explain how it works?

Comment: Show us a [MCVE], what have you attempted, show us your effort. This is pure laziness on your part *Can somebody write a piece of working code and explain how it works?* This is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this program can help you. It might not be perfect but it's close to what you ask about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char str[5000];
    char *ptr;
    char *words[5000];
    FILE * fp = fopen("hi.txt", "r");
    fgets(str, 49, fp);             // read 49 characters
    ptr = strtok(str, ",.; ");         // split our findings around the " "
    int i = 0;
    while(ptr != NULL)  // while there's more to the string
    {
        words[i]= ptr;
        i++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ",.; "); // and keep splitting
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[j]);
    }
}
```

file `hi.txt`

```
foo, bar. baz; bletch.
```

Test

```
./a.out
foo
bar
baz
bletch
```

Comment: Detail `fgets(str, 49, fp);             // read 49 characters` reads up to 48 characters.